# How can I access the React useQuery data result?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Currently, when using react query - I can access the response from "data" like...

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(
  'MyQuery',
  () => {
    setNewdata(data)
    return getMyQuery()      
  }
)
```

then I can .map through the page response like ...

```
return ({data.data.response.data.map((item) => (...))
```

Q: Is there way I can shorten the long data.data.response.data list to something shorter like

```
newdata = data.data.response.data
```

and then...

```
{newdata.map((post) => (...)
```

I do not know where to access -"data" before it is output to the page. Can you help with this?

Thanks for your help in advance

I tried useState to update using `setNewdata(data)` but it did not show up correctly...

Update: I added async like this below - is it correct?

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(
  'MyQuery',
  async  () => {
    setNewdata(data)
    return await getMyQuery()      
  }
)
```

If I console.log(data) after useQuery it is populated with the response.

Comment: have you try await?

Comment: what do you get when you console.log `data`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes I just added async (in the original post). Also when I console.log(data) after useQuery it is populated with the response. 

setNewdata is not updating (where it is) because I think it is Before the query?

Answer (score 1):

First, `setNewData()` has absolutely no place in this code. `data` is undefined where you're trying to use it. You also do not need to set the `data` result into local component state; the `useQuery` hook takes care of state management already.

---

You can make your query results more opaque by simply transforming the result before returning it.

You can do that either within `getMyQuery()` or by using a [selector](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#query-data-selectors) in `useQuery()`

```jsx
const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(["MyQuery"], getMyQuery, {
  select: ({ data }) => data.response.data,
});

return data.map((post) => (
  { /* ... */ }
));
```

---

Unnecessary object nesting in API response data is a pet peeve of mine. I highly recommend simplifying the response format if possible.

Comment: I think the `select` option of `useQuery` would be better for these kind of things.

Comment: @ivanatias nice, I hadn't seen that feature. Will update my anwer

Comment: Thanks to all for the code improvements from this react query newbie - all very helpful

Answer (score 0):

whats stopping you from doing..

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(
  'MyQuery',
  async  () => {
    setNewdata(data) // not sure how you set data here before it exists?
    return await getMyQuery() // im assuming this is where the data comes from?   
  }
)
const newdata = data.data.response.data

return ({newdata.map((item) => (...))
```

Comment: There's no need for `async / await` here. `useQuery` expects the function to return a promise

Comment: the code in general looks odd to me but I'm just going along with his specific question..